# Layered, not stacked column graph in Excel

Tags: data-visualization, excel

I want to layer (superimpose) one column graph on another in Excel. So it would be like a stacked column graph, except that each column for a given category on the x-axis would have its origin at 0 on the y-axis. My data are before and after scores. By layering the columns instead of putting them side-by-side, it would be easier to visualize the magnitude and direction of the difference between the two scores. I've seen this done with R, but can't find examples in Excel. Anyone ever attempted this?

Comment: Could you upload (possibly via a file hosting service if you don't yet have enough rep to upload pictures) or point to an example as to what exactly you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the 3D suggestion and it worked. But the other answer I discovered was to choose a Clustered Column graph and click 'Format Data Series' and change the 'overlap' percentage to 100%. I'm using a Mac so it's slightly different, but the person who helped me with this was on a PC and I've used PC's mainly. What I ended up discovering is that using 90% looked quite nice, but 100% will achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing for my thesis presentation. It's a little tricky and I made it by myself. To do it, you have to create a 3D bar graph (not a stacked one), in which your columns are put in front of each other. You have to make sure that all the taller columns in each X cell are behind the shorter columns in that cell on the X axis.

Once you created that graph, you can rotate the 3D graph in a way that it looks like a 2D graph (by resetting the axes values to zero). Now you have a bar graph, in which every bar has different columns and all of the columns start at zero. ;)

Comment: Working with this interface is a pain for newbies and I don't know how to comment under the post of Pinguin_Knight. But I am referring to him now: sometimes such graphs are pretty needed and useful. For example, in my thesis, it was the best choice. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Change the post score to (post - pre), then you can proceed with making the stacked bar chart.

**Long and correct answer:** DO NOT DO THIS. Clustered bar chart is much better because:

1. The visual line for comparison is the same line anyway, you're not facilitating the understanding in any means.
2. Any kind of overlapping of the bars conceals the area of the post-score, which induces visual distortion. A pre-score of 10 and a post score of 20 should have a column area ratio of 1:2. But if you completely overlap them, it'd be reduced to 1:1. Partial overlapping is equally problematic.